# Where to apply xmodmap for systemwide usage?

Tags: rhel, xmodmap

I need to apply a custom xmodmap for all users at the start. Where do I need to put it? I have thought at `/etc/rc.local`? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` won't work for this situation, because xmodmap requires an X server to talk to.

I know that /etc/X11/Xmodmap is part of the xorg-x11-xinit package on RHEL and Fedora, so make your changes there.  They will be used when any new X session starts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with `xmodmap`, but you can always make a `.xmodmaprc` file and put it in `/etc/skel`. The file will be copied to all new users' home, thus applying the settings.

Comment: This won't affect any existing users or users with already-created home directories (for example, from a network file system).

Comment: @jsbillings Yeah, sure, you are absolutely right.